# Accessing public Calendar using EWS Managed API 2.0?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am getting started with EWS Managed API 2.0 using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn567668.

I would like to know how can I access Public calendar which has a name like "Pub Cons"?

How can I check if this calendar exists or not? How can I loop through all the public calendars?

I don't have much experience with Exchange. So, apologies if I can't provide much more information. Let me know if you need more info.

**Update:**
Exchange version: 2013 CU13
Public calendar is located in a public folder

Comment: What is a Public Calendar eg is it a Calendar in a Public Folder ? is it a Calendar in Shared Mailbox or Group or Team etc ? What version of Exchange are you using ?

Comment: Hi Glen, I only know the version of exchange, but I don't know yet what kind of calendar it is. I will get back as soon as possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do I have to know the name of the public folder?

Comment: Yes you would need to know the name and path to the Public Folder if that's what it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this in your code:

```
Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
```

Here is another post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947788/how-to-retrieve-public-calendars-from-ews). Perhaps it will help.